# DataBricks UnityCatalog create table fails with "Failed to acquire a SAS token UnauthorizedAccessException: PERMISSION_DENIED: request not authorized"

Tags: databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I'm new to DataBricks Unity Catalog and I'm trying to follow the quickstart notebook on https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/unity-catalog-example-notebook.html.

It seems to me I did whatever I had to do:

- I created a Databricks access connector in Azure (which becomes a managed identity)
- I created a storage Account ADLS Gen2 (DAtalake with hierarchical namespace) plus container
- On my datalake container I assigned Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the managed identity above
- I created a new Databricks Premium Workspace
- I created a new metastore in Unity Catalog that "binds" the access connector to the DataLake
- Bound the metastore to the premium databricks workspace
- I gave my Databricks user Admin permission on the above Databricks workspace
- I created a new cluster in the same premium workspaces, choosing framework 11.1 and "single user" access mode
- I ran the workspace, which correctly created a new catalog, assinged proper rights to it, created a schema, confirmed that I am the owner for that schema

The only (but most important) SQL command of the same notebook that fails is the one that tries to create a managed Delta table and insert two records:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quickstart_catalog_mauromi.quickstart_schema_mauromi.quickstart_table
  (columnA Int, columnB String) PARTITIONED BY (columnA);
```

When I run it, it starts working and in fact it starts creating the folder structure for this delta table in my storage account
[image]

, however then it fails with the following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Failed to acquire a SAS token for list on /data/a3b9da69-d82a-4e0d-9015-51646a2a93fb/tables/eab1e2cc-1c0d-4ee4-9a57-18f17edcfabb/_delta_log due to java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.databricks.sql.managedcatalog.acl.UnauthorizedAccessException: PERMISSION_DENIED: request not authorized
```

Please consider that I didn't have any folder created under "unity-catalog" container before running the table creation command. So it seems that is can successfully create the folder structure, but after it creates the "table" folder, it can't acquare "the SAS token".

So I can't understand since I am an admin in this workspace and since Databricks managed identity is assigned the contributor role on the storage container, and since Databricks actually starts creating the other folders. What else should I configure?

Answer (score 5):

You can actually be much more restrictive in your Azure ADLS Gen2 with Unity and Databricks Access Connector. `Storage Blob Data Contributor` or `Owner` rights at the storage account level are NOT required and usually not desired in an enterprise context. When testing this, I identified that the following access rights are sufficient:

1. [`Storage Blob Delegator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-delegator) at the storage account level.
2. [`Storage Blob Data Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor) at the storage account container level.

In addition, make sure that the Firewall of the storage account is configured to allow access from Databricks (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/azure-managed-identities#--recommended-for-vnet-injected-workspaces-configure-trusted-access-to-azure-storage-based-on-your-managed-identity) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-from-azure-resource-instances)) and ensure that CORS is configured according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/storage-cors).

Answer (score 1):

I found it: you need to only to assign, at container level, the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the Azure Databricks Connector. In fact, you need to assign the same role and the same connector at STORAGE ACCOUNT level.
I couldn't find this information in the documentation and I frankly can't understand why this is needed since the delta table path was created.

However, this way, it works.

Comment: Much appreciated, had been trying to solve this issue for a week and the owner permission solved it straight away!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by doing the following:

- Grant the "Access Connector for Azure Databricks" the permission "Storage Blob Data Reader" at the Storage Account level.
- Grant the "Access Connector for Azure Databricks" the permission "Storage Blob Data Contributor" at the container level used by the workspace.

That keeps the permissions a bit more restrictive without having to go down the 'Owner' level.